# Access variadic template argument of class X inside class Y<X>

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have some graph classes that can inherit from each other to provide the functionality needed in different cases (directed graph, traversable graph, nested graph, etc).

In order to make it possible to use the final derived types, these are provided as template arguments to the base classes. This way, for instance `Edge::GetSource` can return the derived class `Node`, and not the base class `Node`.

To make things simple, the graph classes take only one template argument: `GraphTypes`. `GraphTypes` in turn takes as template arguments all the needed derived graph classes. This makes it very easy to make changes to the types used in the graph classes, as only `GraphTypes` need to be changed.

```cpp
template<class GraphT, class NodeT, class EdgeT>
class GraphTypes {
public:
   using GraphType = GraphT;
   using NodeType = NodeT;
   using EdgeType = EdgeT;
}; // GraphTypes


template<class GraphTypes>
class Edge {
private:
   using GraphType = typename GraphTypes::GraphType;
   using NodeType = typename GraphTypes::NodeType;
   using EdgeType = typename GraphTypes::EdgeType;

public:
   NodeType &GetSource();

protected:
   NodeType *m_pSource;
}; // Edge


template<class GraphTypes>
inline NodeType &Edge<GraphTypes>::GetSource() {
   return *m_pSource;
} // Edge::GetSource
```

This is working great! But now I want to add an optional `Context` argument. In some cases, a context object needs to passed around while working on the graph and be made aware, for instance, when `Edge::SetSource` is called.

My idea is to add a variadic template argument. This way graph classes that need no context can just omit it. But how can I add a variadic template argument to `GraphTypes` and then use it inside the other graph classes that have `GraphTypes` as an template argument?

```cpp
template<class GraphT, class NodeT, class EdgeT, class ...ContextT>
class GraphTypes {
public:
   // error C3520: 'ContextT': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
   using ContextType = ContextT;
}; // GraphTypes


template<class GraphTypes>
class Edge {
private:
   using ContextType = typename GraphTypes::ContextType;

public:
   // error C3543: 'GraphTypes::ContextType': does not contain a parameter pack
   void SetSource(NodeType &Source, ContextType &...Context);
}; // Edge


template<class GraphTypes>
void Edge<GraphTypes>::SetSource(NodeType &Source, ContextType &...Context) {
   if(&Source == m_pSource)
      return;
      
   // I think this should work, but open to suggestions ;)
   std::initializer_list<bool>{ (Context.PreSetSource(*this), true)... };

   m_pSource = &Source;

   std::initializer_list<bool>{ (Context.PostSetSource(*this), true)... };
} // Edge::SetSource
```

Comment: You can make `ContextType` be equal to `ContextT...` if size of `ContextT...` is 1, and to `void` otherwise. Then in `Edge` you can define two overloads and SFINAE-out one of them depending on the `void`-ness of `ContextType`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, @Evg! Not sure how to set `ContextType`, though. Would you care to give me a pointer? Or even make a full answer?

Comment: Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Gzj3EMrv7 The answer depends on how you want `SetSource` interface look like. There could be different solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Evg! But I just realized that some of the functions that may have a context must be virtual. So then SFINAE does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can conditionally derived from two classes then.

Comment: Do you mean to have two variants of each class, one with context and one without, and then just inherit from the one I need in each case?

Comment: Yes. https://godbolt.org/z/7K93MfcKW

Comment: To avoid code duplication, CRTP could be helpful.

Comment: Very interesting! That could work :)